# onClick button change innerHtml without stopping snare drum (Javascript / JQuery)

Tags: javascript

Every beat has a drum snare (1,2,3,4)
So "beat" id it's a screen that shows the count.

I want, without stopping the count from the memory, if I click the "beat" button to write "disable" on the screen (1,2,3,4).
If I click enable the beat, continue from where it was left and write enable.
But I do not want the count from the memory to stop. Is it possible?

beat means screen on css
k means  snare sound on sequencer.
Pattern means  sequencer pattern
step means  beat on sequencer

```
<button id="beat" onclick="playPattern()">Disable</button>\

function playPattern() {
    for (var k in Pattern) {
    
    if (Pattern[k][Step] == "1") {
        document.getElementById("beat").innerHTML = "1";
    }
    if (Pattern[k][Step] == "2") {
        document.getElementById("beats").innerHTML = "2";
    }
    if (Pattern[k][Step] == "3") {
        document.getElementById("beats").innerHTML = "3";
    }
    if (Pattern[k][Step] == "4") {
        document.getElementById("beats").innerHTML = "4";
    }
    else  {
    document.getElementById('beat').onclick = function() {
                 beat.innerHTML = 'Disable';
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand your issue. It would be helpful if you give more info and Pattern object.

Comment: Imagine that is a drum machine that counts from 1 to 4 and has a screen. Every time you hear the snare drum , you see one number on screen (Its a dance beat 1 2 3 4). I want if you click on button (beat id)  , to disable innerHTML 1,2,3,4 on screen, but without stop  or pause the play button. Only the numbers on screen to stop. Whatever I do , I always see the count...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of difficulty understanding your use case, but this example should show how you can store the count in a variable called `count` and display that value on the screen whenever you choose. (It also uses the built-in `setInterval` function to advance the count every second.)

The `disabled` variable keeps track of whether the display is in a disabled state, and the `playOrPause` function uses this information to decide whether to 1) resume the timer and show the current count or 2) stop the timer and show the "Disabled" message.

```js
const
  pattern = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  beat = document.getElementById("beat"),
  beats = document.getElementById("beats");

let
  count = 0,
  disabled = true,
  timer = null;

beat.addEventListener("click", playOrPause);

function playOrPause() {
  if(disabled === true){
    timer = setInterval(advanceCount, 1000);
    beats.textContent = count;
    beat.textContent = "PAUSE";
    disabled = false;
  }
  else{
    clearInterval(timer);
    beats.textContent = "(Disabled)";
    beat.textContent = "PLAY";
    disabled = true;
  }
}

function advanceCount(){
  if(count == 4){ count = 1; }
  else{ count++; }
  beats.textContent = count;
}
```

```css
#beat{ margin: 1rem; }
#beats{ margin-left: 2rem; font-size: 1.5rem; }
```

```html
<button id="beat">PLAY</button>
<div id="beats"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is great, I'm working on it.. Can you add a sample sound on your project that follows the numbers? Is it possible (kick , snare, hihat, beep anything)

Comment: I've actually never worked with audio, but I googled it and it looks like all it takes is `const snareNoise = new Audio("snare_noise.mp3"); snareNoise.play();` (assuming you have a file called "snare_noise.mp3") -- so you could declare the variable globally and just call the `.play` method every time you advance the count. (I can't add this functionality in the Stack Overflow snippet because I can't save an mp3 file to their server, but [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) makes it look relatively straightforward.)